# Unreal - Create Widget in blueprint - fills the screen instead of keeping its dimensions

Tags: unreal-engine4, hud

I use "Create Widget" -> "Add to viewport" to add one of my widgets to the viewport

**the problem is that the widget fills the whole screen**

I then added a canvas panel in my widget but **then I cannot choose to anchor it to the bottom of the screen**

how do I do this ?

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential way of going about anchoring the widget to the bottom of the screen would be to make your canvas panel the size of your screen and set the position of the content of the widget individually and anchor it as shown below.
[image: Picture of a widget being anchored to the bottom right]

Another way you can go about doing this is by clicking on your size box, going to the details tab on the right, clicking on anchors and then the option shown below (3rd from top on the right most column), This will anchor your size box to the bottom of the screen.
[image: setting size box's anchor to bottom of screen]

Ill also link you to a discussion I found that might be useful to you for solving your issue.

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/839144/dynamically-set-widget-position-on-canvas-panel.html

Let me know if this solves your problem. If not I'll try my best to help you out in any way possible :)

Comment: the size box only allows to anchor relative to the canvas, not the screen, so the only option is to set the canvas fullscreen or position the component dynamicaly...anchors wont work here, hence the question

Comment: so did you manage to set the position dynamically using the details in the link above? If not, why are the options not suitable for you?

Comment: I just set the canvas to full screen but it's meh